# Xamarin.Forms - Add external dll

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin.forms, uwp, dllimport

I am trying to load a dll (ACRCloud - libacrcloud_extr_tool.dll) within my Xamarin.Forms.UWP App. When I try to access it, I get an error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\libacrcloud_extr_tool.dll': Access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Is there a way to access this .dll in a Xamarin.Forms Project (starting with UWP)?

Comment: Maybe you have to unlock a DLL on OS level? https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file

Comment: Yes this helped accessing the dll. If I roll out my app, is the dll still unblocked?

Comment: I posted my comment as answer, please accept and upvote if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At times, you may download a file from the Internet or receive one by
>   email. Windows classifies certain files as unsafe downloads and
>   attachments by identifying the files type and the security settings
>   for each file...

It seems like you have to `unlock` the dll on OS level before you could use it in your project.
 More information can be found [here](http://thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-blocked-access-file).

P.S.: It should not affect the distribution process of your application, since the app bundle will be considered from a trusted source.